# Can a .Net program launching a browser window cause the browser window to become unresponsive?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process

I have the following C# code:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
myProcess.Start();
```

Which when required opens up a webpage that has been developed by a customer.

The customer is complaining that the browser window is unresponsive, can't be closed and that the page times out.

Is there anything in my code that could be causing this? Or it the issue likely to be with IE/ the customer developed webpage?

As far as my understanding is what I'm doing is no different from my typing "iexplore.exe url" on the command line, I just want to be 100% sure that I'm not at fault before I give this issue back to our customer.

**EDIT**

Looks like it was an issue with the customer's machine...

Comment: Can you tell us what is value of `url`

Comment: Url is as far as I can tell an asp.net webpage. It's a customer specific page that isn't accessible out with their intranet.

Comment: There is no problem with your code. If I simply replace `url` with `www.google.com`, it works wonderfully. Please check `url'....

Comment: Try hardcoding the URL to something like google.com to test if it's working, if it is, it might be be a url problem, i.e.maybe there's something wrong with the aspx page or that APSX page has a bug

Comment: I tested using google.com and that "Worked fine on my machine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end your code is indeed (almost) equivalent to running that command on the command prompt (i.e. from `CMD.EXE`) - you might want to set `UseShellExecute` to false, however.
But that should have nothing to do with the issues seen.

So unless you do something fancy with the `Process` instance after it has been started (or even with the `Process.Handle` property), the issues seen should be a result of the website being opened (or the Internet Explorer installation, etc.) but not your code.

As a cross-check you can ask the customer to open the URL in question manually, using Internet Explorer. It should exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: That is what I've just asked them to do, I've asked them to type iexplore.exe <<URL>> into a command line and see if if works.

I am 99% sure it is an issue with the webpage, but I don't want to say that all smug and then get egg in my face.